# Constructing graph of points in 3D with edges weighted by distance

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geometry, machine-learning

I have a set of data in $\mathbf{R}^3$ for which I want to construct a $k$-nearest-neighbors graph whose edges are weighted by the distance of each point to its neighbors. Is there a way to do this without reinventing the wheel, since Mathematica already contains a `NearestNeighborGraph` symbol? As far as I can tell, it outputs the graph I want but doesn't weight the edges by euclidean distance between the vertices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NearestNeighborGraph` uses the point coordinates as vertex names.

Therefore, if `g` is your `NearestNeighborGraph` then this will set its weights:

```
SetProperty[g, EdgeWeight -> EuclideanDistance @@@ EdgeList[g]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Right before you posted I figured out a worse way of doing it:
`g = 
 Graph[VertexList[#], EdgeList[#], 
    EdgeWeight -> edgeLength /@ EdgeList[#]] &@g`. Would you happen to know why this makes Mathematica "forget" about the vertex locations, such that if I display it it no longer shows points in 3D?

Comment: Because graph no longer has 3D `VertexCoordinates`, you rebuild the graph from just the list of vertices and edges, and it recalculates the coordinates in 2D. A 3D point essentially becomes just a name for a vertex.